# Online tools for plotting and deriving formulas from set of data?

Tags: matrices, graphing-functions, online-resources

I have a matrix of 20x3 decimal values. I would like to have them in a graph, with one plot for each of the three y values. I would also like approximated formulas for each of the three. Are there any online tools that let me do this? Would be particularly happy if there is a tool that lets me import the data directly from my OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet, but it's not necessary.

If you are confused, it is probably my fault. Please excuse me for improper terminology, if any.

Comment: I have never used it, but maybe [this can help](http://jsxgraph.org/)